# Pegar um índice do array no PHP com foreach

Tags: php

Tenho esse código para gravar em array o resultado do Mysql

```
    $sql = "SELECT valor_cobrar FROM pedidos order by id_usuario";
    $userinfo = array();
    $result = $conn->query($sql);
    if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    // output data of each row
     while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        $userinfo[] = $row;
    }
    } else {
    echo "0 results";
    }
print_r($userinfo);
```

retorna

```
Array ( [0] => Array ( [id] => 36 [data] => 2019-05-10 00:00:00 [cod_transacao] => asdsad [tipo] => boleto [valor] => 30 [valor_cobrar] => 35 [status] => 3 [tipo_transacao] => saldo [id_usuario] => 34 ) [1] => Array ( [id] => 34 [data] => 2019-05-17 14:21:50 [cod_transacao] => D1E503F5-9D2D-4957-9902-7773E0477071 [tipo] => boleto [valor] => 20 [valor_cobrar] => 21.47 [status] => 1 [tipo_transacao] => saldo [id_usuario] => 95 ) [2] => Array ( [id] => 35 [data] => 2019-05-17 14:23:18 [cod_transacao] => 8574188D-ED9A-4216-B48D-CADC38CE56B7 [tipo] => boleto [valor] => 40 [valor_cobrar] => 42.47 [status] => 1 [tipo_transacao] => saldo [id_usuario] => 95 ) )
```

Preciso pegar com o foreach apenas o valor do índice `[valor_cobrar`] do array.
Estou fazendo assim, mas só retorna o valor do `[id]`, como faria para resolver isso?

```
foreach($userinfo as $item) {
    $key   = key($item);
    $value = current($item);

    echo "$key => $value\n";
}
```

retorna

```
id => 36 id => 34 id => 35
```

Comment: Dúvida: se você precisa apenas de `valor_cobrar`, por que selecionou todas as colunas do banco?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Se você quer obter o valor da coluna `valor_cobrar` para cada registro retornado de sua query

```php
foreach ($userinfo as $item) {
    echo $item['valor_cobrar'];
}
```

Se você desejar obter o valor somente da coluna `valor_cobrar` para um registro específico:

```php
$uid  = 5; // O id do usuário que você quer buscar o valor
$sql  = "SELECT valor_cobrar FROM pedidos where id_usuario = ?";
$stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
$stmt->execute([$uid]);

$valorCobrar = $stmt->fetchColumn(0); // 0 por que selecionamos apenas uma coluna na query

echo $valorCobrar;
```

**Sugestões de leitura**

- PHP [PDO](https://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/book.pdo.php) Book. No exemplo usei o método [PDO::FetchColumn](https://php.net/manual/pt_BR/pdostatement.fetchcolumn.php)
- [Preapre Statements](https://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/pdo.prepare.php) para aumentar a segurança nas queries

Answer (score 1):

Tente assim:

```
foreach($userinfo as $item) {
       echo $item['valor_cobrar'];
    }
```